# I've got this answer that had been deleted but I don't know why

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer, editing-help

I wrote an answer to ['developing a GUI in C# on cosmos'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429726/developing-a-gui-in-c-sharp-on-cosmos-os) - which you can easily find with a little googling. It was deleted and downvoted and I don't know why. What sorts of things should I add (or remove) in order to make it acceptable? It went a little like this:

> Man, although I know this might be too late but I got something for you. Cosmos OS has had large changes since 2010 and it's gotten new features too - including VGA support, debugging and file systems!
>
> Download the newest version right [here.](https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos) There should be a wiki as well that documents [how to create a GUI in Cosmos!](https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos/wiki/Creating-a-GUI---The-basics) I'd happily change this answer to discuss the article but it'd make things more complicated.

I had links to a VGADriver article and the latest stable release of Cosmos in order to help the dude. Adding code was going to be too complicated to explain - should I have added code to it? I'm not so sure how to deal with this…

Comment: If the text your quoted here is all (or most) of your answer, that explains why it was deleted.  Your answer says exactly **nothing**.  All you did was advertise new features of another version and point where to get it.  As an answer, it sucks.  It might have been passabl as a comment

Comment: @psubsee2003 through... the question kinda asks for that kind of answers.

Comment: @Braiam Which is kinda why I'm torn on how to edit it. Should I add the code on the article that I've referenced?

Comment: Also *"Man, although I know this might be too late but I got something for you"*?  SO is not a forum.

Comment: Answering awful questions is not advisable, as it leads to deleted answers, heartache, and ghonnosyphaherpaloids.